# How to add Button for downloading excel file in Acumatica

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, webforms, acumatica

I'm trying to add button to Users Maintenance and on button's click download excel file, containing some data. I have created PXAction and it's method as above:

```
public PXAction<Users> getUsers;

[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Get Users", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select,Visible = true), PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
public IEnumerable GetUsers(PXAdapter adapter)
{
    var accessByRoles = PXSelect<RolesInGraph>.Select(this.Base);
    var usersByRole = PXSelect<UsersInRoles>.Select(this.Base);
    var dt = GetTable();//GetTable returns some DataTable just for test now
    XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook();
    workbook.Worksheets.Add(dt, "UserAccessRigths");
    using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        workbook.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"UserAccessRigths.xlsx\"");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", MyMemoryStream.ToArray().Length.ToString());
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(MyMemoryStream.ToArray());
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Everything work but the part where the download in the browser must start.
I'm getting as response the excel, but it's not being downloaded.
Here is the response I'm getting in the browser:
[image]

I will be very grateful if someone can help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try PXRedirectToFileException to redirect the user browser to the Excel file. Default behavior from mainstream browser is to detect Excel mime type by extension and initiate a download. Second parameter of PXRedirectToFileException is used to force download.

```
throw new PXRedirectToFileException(new PX.SM.FileInfo(Guid.NewGuid(),
                                                       "UserAccessRigths.xlsx",
                                                       null,
                                                       MyMemoryStream.ToArray()),
                                    true);
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I need. Thanks.

Comment: PXRedirectToFileException cannot be found and I cannot seem to find what kind of library from google.

Comment: PXRedirectToFileException is in the PX.Data namespace of PX.Data assembly. This question is relevant to Acumatica ERP Framework and PXRedirectToFileException is part of that framework.