# How to use PXRedirectToUrlException in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

In Stock Items screen we created a button and on this button click we are downloading some certificates from third party and storing into files section. we also created a button GET CERTIFICATE on this button action, we want user to redirect to GetFile.ashx screen. Like how standard Acumatica will take us when we click on link from Files popup.

We are using 2019 R1, here is my code sample:

```
throw new PXRedirectToUrlException(string.Format("~/Frames/GetFile.ashx?fileID={0}", fileId), "Certificate") { Mode = PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.NewWindow };
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks there is a good example of this found in `SOShipmentEntry` (`PrintCarrierLabels` method) if you have the fileid already:

```
string targetUrl = PXRedirectToFileException.BuildUrl(mergedFile.UID);
throw new PXRedirectToUrlException(targetUrl, "Print Labels");
```

You can also use `PXRedirectToFileException` if you have the `FileInfo` object:

```
throw new PXRedirectToFileException(file, true);
```

These might open/download the file as I am not sure of the results. These are examples I found in the Acumatica source for working with fileid.

If you really want the user to download the file this is a good post: [How to add Button for downloading excel file in Acumatica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43998006/how-to-add-button-for-downloading-excel-file-in-acumatica/44004781#44004781)