# Cannot find the code definition for "Email Purchase Order" Action In Purchase Order Screen

Tags: customization, acumatica

I would like to Customize "Email Purchase Order" action in Action folder of Purchase Order Screen.
I don't find the code where it is located.

And suppose if it is presented in dll, Can we customize that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't find the code where it is located.

It is not a standard action, some trickery is involved in the way it redirects the action.

It goes through the `POOrderEntry.Action` event handler first before it is routed to `POOrderEntry.Notification` event handler to send the email.

You can customize it by creating a graph extension on `POOrderEntry` and overriding the `Notification` method.

[image]

In the `Notification` method override you can use the condition `adapter.Menu == "Email Purchase Order"` to determine if the call to `Notification` method originated from the `Email Purchase Order` action menu item.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you help Hugues. Presently when "Email Purchase" action is performed, it sends a mail in which it contains a PO report(pdf document format) but my requirements is, I need to send my pdf document instead of PO report. How do i do that?

Comment: If you have access to the content of the file, create a memory stream, write file content to the stream and redirect to the file. I have an answer on this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44004781/7376238